# CSS Styling text areas like notebook-look

Tags: html, css, textarea

It is possible to style a text area so each row have a dotted
underline (like a notebook or a notes-block)?

The number of lines should be fixed to lets say 10.

Comment: Just use a background image?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Here's probably what you looking for:

[image: line]

```html
<style type="text/css">
textarea {
 background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynxjD.png) repeat-y;
 width: 600px;
 height: 300px;
 font: normal 14px verdana;
 line-height: 25px;
 padding: 2px 10px;
 border: solid 1px #ddd;
}

</style>
<textarea>
    Textarea with style example
    Line 1
    Line 2
    Line 3
    Line 4
    Line 5
    Line 6
    Line 7
    Line n
</textarea>
```

Or you can read this articles that tells you how to do it from scratch:

[Creating a Notebook Background](http://www.webdesign.org/photoshop/web-layout/creating-a-notebook-background.9347.html)

Comment: you can add: border: none; that will make it better

Comment: You can dynamically create an SVG background image based on the line height: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18572303/multiline-questionaire-editable/18585281

Answer (score 45):

Pure CSS3

```
<style>
    html{ height: 100%; }
    body
    {
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
    }
    textarea
    {
        border: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #DDDDDD;
        display: block;
        font-family: 'Marck Script',cursive;
        font-size: 22px;
        line-height: 50px;
        margin: 2% auto;
        padding: 11px 20px 0 70px;
        resize: none;
        height: 689px;
        width: 530px;

        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top , transparent, transparent 49px,#E7EFF8 0px), -moz-radial-gradient(4% 50%, circle closest-corner, #f5f5f5, #f5f5f5 39%, transparent 0%), -moz-radial-gradient(3.9% 46% , circle closest-corner, #CCCCCC, #CCCCCC 43.5%, transparent 0%); 
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top , transparent, transparent 49px,#E7EFF8 0), -webkit-radial-gradient(4% 50%, circle closest-corner, #f5f5f5, #f5f5f5 39%, transparent 0%), -webkit-radial-gradient(3.9% 46%, circle closest-corner, #cccccc, #cccccc 43.5%, transparent 0%);

        -webkit-background-size:  100% 50px;
        background-size: 100% 50px;
    }
</style>
```

the result you can see this link: http://jsfiddle.net/Wolfsblvt/qc9rgm7r/

Comment: The link is no longer there, can you upload it elsewhere?

Comment: That's why you shouldn't use your personal website to upload examples. I think JSFiddle is way more reliable.

Comment: It takes 5 seconds to do a fiddle on your own. This is one, with the exact code: http://jsfiddle.net/Wolfsblvt/qc9rgm7r/

Comment: this is very cool! dynamic line heights, no external file dependency, no extra request!

Comment: Great solution, thanks! If You want the lines to scroll along with the textarea's contents, add `background-attachment: local`.

Answer (score 7):

I took the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12675075/441662) and upgraded it to SCSS to make it configurable. You can now easily change size and color of the holes and rules and everything will size accordingly.

Also, I added another example that uses an editable div instead of a textarea.

[image: example]

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/plantface/g66fcp9h/)

```
// rule config
$rule-height: 20px; // <-- primary parameter

   $font-size: min(max($rule-height - 9, 8pt), 13pt);
   $rule-mask-height: $rule-height - 1;
   $rule-padding-top: $rule-height + 2;
   $rule-padding-right: $rule-height;
   $rule-padding-left: $rule-height * 2;

// colors
$hole-fill-color: #f5f5f5;
$hole-shadow: #CCCCCC;
$paper-color: #FFFFFF;
$line-color: #E7EFF8;
```

Unfortunately, Stackoverflow doesn't support SCSS, so I just included a snapshot of one fixed configuration here:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Reenie+Beanie");

html { height: 100%; }
body { background-color: #f5f5f5; }

.editable {
  color: #000000;
  border: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #DDDDDD;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  /*font-family: 'Marck Script', cursive;*/
  font-family: 'Reenie Beanie', cursive;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin: 2% auto;
  padding: 22px 20px 3px 40px;
  resize: none;
  min-height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, transparent, transparent 19px, #E7EFF8 0px), -moz-radial-gradient(4% 50%, circle closest-corner, #f5f5f5, #f5f5f5 39%, transparent 0%), -moz-radial-gradient(3.9% 46%, circle closest-corner, #CCCCCC, #CCCCCC 43.5%, transparent 0%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, transparent, transparent 19px, #E7EFF8 0), -webkit-radial-gradient(4% 50%, circle closest-corner, #f5f5f5, #f5f5f5 39%, transparent 0%), -webkit-radial-gradient(3.9% 46%, circle closest-corner, #CCCCCC, #CCCCCC 43.5%, transparent 0%);
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 20px;
  background-size: 100% 20px;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="editable">Textarea: This is the first line.
See, how the text fits here, also if there is a linebreak at the end? It works nicely.

  Great.
</textarea>

<div class="editable" contenteditable>Editable div: This is the first line.<br>
  See, how the text fits here, also if there is a linebreak at the end?<br>
  It works nicely.<br>
  <br>
  Great.
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

These solutions don’t support overflowing textarea. So scrolling only scroll the text not the background. To support scrolling, you should add “**background-attachment: local;**” to the textarea css.

Comment: This was what I needed to use with the accepted answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28665159/how-can-i-underline-all-rows-in-textarea

Answer (score 2):

If you are still interested in this topic you can check the [Paper text Area examples - created with css only](http://fivera.net/paper-text-area-created-with-css-only-editable-example/) on fivera's blog.
Cool thing about it is that you can play with the examples on the spot.

Comment: It's best not to rely on a link to another webpage when answering a question. You can't be sure that the link will always be accessible.

Answer (score 1):

Scroll breaks every solution, a complete solution for this should also make lines scroll with text. This is difficult to accomplish just by adding a background image to a textarea.