# How can I underline all rows in textarea?

Tags: html, css

How can I underline all rows in textarea?

I need in something [like this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/km8pwik21nc4zr9/Screenshot%202015-02-23%2003.15.37.png?dl=0).

P.S. Textarea has style `padding: 10px`

I can't you background, because if I'll scroll this textarea, text will look [like this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l3bhxa21daodz5x/Screenshot%202015-02-23%2003.26.14.png?dl=0).

Thank you!