# Underlining lines in full width, not only text

Tags: css, border, underline

Hi,
I'm currently trying to set something up with HTML/CSS that looks like a post-it note.

An *Image* of what I'm aiming at

[image]

Please note that **every line** should be underlined, no matter how many characters are in that line. Also every new line should be underlined completely.

HTML:

```
<p>
    <img src="http://trööt.net/img/pin.png" alt="Stecknadel"/>
    <font>Heading</font><br />
    <span class="blockMargin">
    <span class="underline">
        <strong>Subheading</strong> text text text
    </span>
    </span>
</p>
```

CSS:

```
p {
    background-Color: #ffc; 
    padding: 1em; 
    width: 40em; 
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 3px 0px rgba(119,119,119,0.7); 
    text-align: justify;
}
img{
    float: None;  
    height: 4em; 
    display: block; 
    margin-left: Auto; 
    margin-right: Auto;
}

.blockMargin{
    display: block; 
    margin-bottom: -1px;
}

.underline{
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #c03;
}
```

This is the code I'm currently using (got the idea already from stackoverflow.com). However, it doesn't underline the lines complete but works exactly like `text-decoration: underline`...

Any ideas? *Maybe I should add that I create this using WordPress and the Nuclear-Theme.*

Thank you very much for your help!

Example on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8w9Lj7nd/

Comment: Please split your HTML and CSS and set up an example of what you have created on JSFiddle.net

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Styling text areas like notebook-look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304436/css-styling-text-areas-like-notebook-look)

Answer (score 9):

http://jsfiddle.net/8w9Lj7nd/1/

There you go.

```
.underline{
border-bottom: 1px dotted #c03;
width: 100%;
display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It looks perfect in JSFiddle... unfortunately, something prevents it from working on my page. The lines aren't displayed at all. I guess Wordpress or the theme somehow do this?!

Comment: inspect the elements or try !important.

Comment: Unlike a true underline, this does not accomplish what `text-decoration-skip-ink` does. A bottom border will run right through descenders.

Comment: It doesn't work as expected. Add more text to break lines, then you can see only the last line is underlined not every one as requested.

Answer (score 2):

This is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304436/css-styling-text-areas-like-notebook-look/48840828):

---

I took the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12675075/441662) and upgraded it to SCSS to make it configurable. You can now easily change size and color of the holes and rules and everything will size accordingly.

Also, I added another example that uses an editable div instead of a textarea.

[image: example]

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/plantface/g66fcp9h/)

```
// rule config
$rule-height: 20px; // <-- primary parameter

   $font-size: min(max($rule-height - 9, 8pt), 13pt);
   $rule-mask-height: $rule-height - 1;
   $rule-padding-top: $rule-height + 2;
   $rule-padding-right: $rule-height;
   $rule-padding-left: $rule-height * 2;

// colors
$hole-fill-color: #f5f5f5;
$hole-shadow: #CCCCCC;
$paper-color: #FFFFFF;
$line-color: #E7EFF8;
```

Unfortunately, Stackoverflow doesn't support SCSS, so I just included a snapshot of one fixed configuration here:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Reenie+Beanie");

html { height: 100%; }
body { background-color: #f5f5f5; }

.editable {
  color: #000000;
  border: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #DDDDDD;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  /*font-family: 'Marck Script', cursive;*/
  font-family: 'Reenie Beanie', cursive;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin: 2% auto;
  padding: 22px 20px 3px 40px;
  resize: none;
  min-height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, transparent, transparent 19px, #E7EFF8 0px), -moz-radial-gradient(4% 50%, circle closest-corner, #f5f5f5, #f5f5f5 39%, transparent 0%), -moz-radial-gradient(3.9% 46%, circle closest-corner, #CCCCCC, #CCCCCC 43.5%, transparent 0%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, transparent, transparent 19px, #E7EFF8 0), -webkit-radial-gradient(4% 50%, circle closest-corner, #f5f5f5, #f5f5f5 39%, transparent 0%), -webkit-radial-gradient(3.9% 46%, circle closest-corner, #CCCCCC, #CCCCCC 43.5%, transparent 0%);
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 20px;
  background-size: 100% 20px;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="editable">Textarea: This is the first line.
See, how the text fits here, also if there is a linebreak at the end? It works nicely.

  Great.
</textarea>

<div class="editable" contenteditable>Editable div: This is the first line.<br>
  See, how the text fits here, also if there is a linebreak at the end?<br>
  It works nicely.<br>
  <br>
  Great.
</div>
```