# How to underline a text (with full width) using CSS

Tags: html, css, text, underline

I've this html code:

```html
<a class="jstree-anchor  jstree-disabled textualstatements-jstreenode-parent" href="#" tabindex="-1" id="td72383_anchor"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon fa fa-folder jstree-themeicon-custom" role="presentation"></i>My example text</a>
```

And this CSS:

```css
.textualstatements-jstreenode-parent {
        text-decoration: underline !important;
        text-decoration-color: #2eaaa1 !important;
        text-decoration-thickness: 2.5px !important;
        text-underline-offset: 2px !important;
        font-weight: bold;
        width: 100%;
        
    }
```

And this is rendered like:
[image]

However, I want the green line to be expanded using the full width from the block, can this be done using text-decoration?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of underline, create bottom border,

```
border-bottom:1px solid #000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use border.

```
p{
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a div and set the bottom-line to green.

```
div {width: 100%; border-bottom: 1px solid #2eaaa1;}
```

Or if you perse want to underline, you can expand the a text with spaces: a lot of & nbsp;.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me.

Here is an explanation already on stackoverflow [CSS Styling text areas like notebook-look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304436/css-styling-text-areas-like-notebook-look/48840828)

```css
.textualstatements-jstreenode-parent {
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: solid #2eaaa1 2.5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<a class="jstree-anchor  jstree-disabled textualstatements-jstreenode-parent" href="#" tabindex="-1" id="td72383_anchor"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon fa fa-folder jstree-themeicon-custom" role="presentation"></i>My example text</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to make width 100% for an anchor tag which is an inline element.
`width:100%` will not have any effect unless the element is `block` or `inline-block`.

Try this

```
.textualstatements-jstreenode-parent {
        text-decoration: underline !important;
        text-decoration-color: #2eaaa1 !important;
        text-decoration-thickness: 2.5px !important;
        text-underline-offset: 2px !important;
        font-weight: bold;
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
    }
```